# Sending Logs to AWS ElasticSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to send logs from the below services to CloudWatch Log group and then further stream it to ElasticSearch service. I am stuck in the log format that needs to be provided.

For sending Config logs, I chose JSON Log format and have given the filter pattern as "{ ("source" => "aws.config") }" but I am getting the attached error.

Could somebody help with the log patterns please.

Services that I am targeting to stream to ES are: S3, EFS, KMS, CloudTrail, CloudWatch, VPC,VPN, ROUTE53, KINESIS, CONFIG,  COGNITO, SNS, ELASTICSEARCH, STS

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The subscription filter pattern for where the source is is `aws.config` is `{ $.source = "aws.config" }`.

You can find out more about filter patterns from the [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it works. So for other services that I mentioned, hopefully { $.source = "aws.service" } will work, isn't it?

Comment: Exactly, you can use the `||` condition so for example `{ $.source = "aws.config"  || $.source = "aws.s3"  }`